# Feature deep copy in rally

Tags: javascript, rally

Actully I want functionality like feature deep copy
Which will copy all the stories and tasks inside those stories in that feature.
I modified the code from StoryDeepCopy but features are not getting populated just stories are only getting populated, I don't know why its happening.
I think the story deep copy app was in version 1.32 which don't have concept of feature or any PortfolioItem but 2.0 version has the support for that.
This may be the reaason.
Any suggestions
This is some of the code from the app

```
  function onChooserClose(chooser, args) {
    if (args.selectedItem) {
      selectedValue = args.selectedItem;
      goButton.setEnabled(true);
      dojo.byId('featureBox').innerHTML = args.selectedItem.FormattedID + ' - ' + args.selectedItem.Name;
    }
  }

  function showChooser() {
    var chooserConfig = {
      fetch:"FormattedID,Name,Description",
      title: 'Feature Chooser'
    };
    chooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, dataSource);
    chooser.addEventListener('onClose', onChooserClose);
    chooser.display();
  }

  rally.addOnLoad(function () {
    goButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
      text: "Copy",
      enabled: false
    });
    goButton.addEventListener('onClick', buttonPressed);
    goButton.display('goButton');

    chooseButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
      text: "Choose"
    });
    chooseButton.addEventListener('onClick', showChooser);
    chooseButton.display('chooseButton');

    showChooser();

    rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.setHelpTopic("252");
  });
});
```

Comment: Here is an app that helps you deep copy portfolio items: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/portfolio-item-copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent of deep copy for features in the app catalog. You are correct that AppSDK1, latest version of which is 1.33 has no concept of PortfolioItem objects. If you want to access Portfolio Items or Blocked Reason, or any other feature introduced in later versions of WS API up to 1.43 this syntax will allow it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.33/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.43"></script>
```

Another variation of this trick is shown in a code fragment below from an app that builds a table of PortfolioItems in AppSDK1 app:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function tableExample() {
       var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('111','222','false','false');
       rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.43");
      function itemQuery() {
         var queryObject = {
           key: "pi",
           type: "portfolioitem",
           fetch: "FormattedID,Name"
         };
         rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
      }
```

This method does not work with v2.0 of WS API.

It has to be used with caution. One thing that definitely will break is around calculations of timebox start and end dates.  That's why many legacy Rally App Catalog apps are still at 1.29.
This is due to changes in API Version 1.30. See [API versioning](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/versioning.jsp) section in the WS API documentation.

Comment: Hi nick I am still not able to fetch the features(PortfolioItem) with the code u gave, still it fetches stories only.Do I need to compile and build it with Rally-app-builder..

Comment: I have appsdk1 app that work with portfoiliitems here: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/pi-with-appsdk1 You do not need to use app builder with appsdk1. I am not sure how it can fetch stories when you set type: "portfolioitem"

Comment: Hi nick with the help of you I am able to run my code but it gaves error like "Requested type name "feature" is unknown." but nowhere I specified feature its PortfolioItem, plz help..thnx in advance