# getting the error while copying feature ""Requested type name "feature" is unknown.""

Tags: rally

This is code what I wrote for this...
    
    
      Feature Deep Copy
      
      
      
      
      
        rally.PortfolioItemDeepCopy = function (rallyDataSource, config) {
            var portfolioitemBuffer = [];
            var firstPortfolioItem = null;
            var firstStory = null;
            var finishedCallback;
            var that = this;
            //dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method, dontFix);
            this._fireEvent = function(eventName, eventArgs) {

```
            if (config && config.eventListeners[eventName] && dojo.isFunction(config.eventListeners[eventName])) {
                config.eventListeners[eventName](that, eventArgs);
            }
        };
        // removes private and read only fields to keep from pushing them up.
        this.filterObject = function (object) {
            return object;
        };      
        this._addObject = function(object, typeName, callback) {
            var item = dojo.clone(object);
            item = this.filterObject(item);
            function errorFunctionWrapper(error) {
                if (dojo.isArray(error.Errors)) {
                    var errorMessage = error.Errors.pop();
                    if (errorMessage.indexOf("Not authorized to create:") >= 0) {
                        errorMessage = "Unable to create an object. This can happen due to a child or task being in a project you do not have write permissions to.";
                    }
                    rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showMessage("error", errorMessage, 10000);
                }
                else if(dojo.isObject(error)&&error.message){
                    rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showMessage("error", error.message, 10000);
                    error = [error.message];
                }
                if (dojo.isFunction(config.onError)) {
                    config.onError(error);
                }
            }
            rallyDataSource.create(typeName, item, callback, errorFunctionWrapper);
        };
        this._copyAllFromBuffer = function() {
            if (portfolioitemBuffer.length > 0) {
                var portfolioitem = portfolioitemBuffer.pop();
                that._copyPortfolioItem(portfolioitem.ref, portfolioitem.parent, that._copyAllFromBuffer);
            }
            else {
                if (finishedCallback) {
                    finishedCallback(firstPortfolioItem);
                }
            }           
        };
        this._addPortfolioItemsToBuffer = function(portfolioitemArray, parentRef) {
            dojo.forEach(portfolioitemArray, function (portfolioitem) {
                portfolioitemBuffer.push({
                    ref: portfolioitem._ref,
                    parent: parentRef
                });
            });
        };
        this._copyPortfolioItem = function(ref, parentRef, callback) {
            rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                var type = "feature"
                that._fireEvent("portfolioitemPreAdd", {portfolioitem:foundObject});
                if (parentRef) {
                    foundObject.Parent = parentRef;
                }
                else {
                    foundObject.Name = "(Copy of) " + foundObject.Name;
                }
                that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (portfolioitemRef) {
                    if (!firstPortfolioItem) {
                        firstPortfolioItem = portfolioitemRef;
                    }
                    that._fireEvent("portfolioitemPostAdd", {});
                    that._addPortfolioItemsToBuffer(foundObject.Children, portfolioitemRef);
                    that._copyStoriesToPortfolioItem(foundObject.Stories, portfolioitemRef, callback);
                    that._copyTasksToStory(foundObject.Tasks, portfolioitemRef, callback);
                }, null);
            });
        };  
        this._copyTasksToStory = function(tasks, storyRef, callback) {
            //Copy the array
            var localTasks = tasks.slice(0);
            if (localTasks.length > 0) {
                var task = localTasks.pop();
                that._copyTask(task._ref, storyRef, function () {
                    that._copyTasksToStory(localTasks, storyRef, callback);
                });
            }
            else {
                callback();
            }
        };
        this._copyStoriesToPortfolioItem = function(stories, portfolioitemRef, callback) {
            //Copy the array
            var localStories = stories.slice(0);
            if (localStories.length > 0) {
                var task = localStories.pop();
                that._copyStory(story._ref, portfolioitemRef, function () {
                    that._copyStoriesToPortfolioItem(localStories, portfolioitemRef, callback);
                });
            }
            else {
                callback();
            }
        };      

        this._copyStory = function(ref, portfolioitemRef, callback) {
            rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                var type = "hierarchicalrequirement";
                foundObject.WorkProduct = portfolioitemRef;
                that._fireEvent("storyPreAdd", {story:foundObject});
                that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (ref, warnings) {
                    if (callback) {
                        that._fireEvent("storyPostAdd", [ref]);
                        callback();
                    }
                }, null);
            });
        };

        this._copyTask = function(ref, storyRef, callback) {
            alert('helooooddddddddddddd task', ref);
            rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function (foundObject) {
                var type = "task";
                foundObject.WorkProduct = storyRef;
                that._fireEvent("taskPreAdd", {task:foundObject});
                that._addObject(foundObject, type, function (ref, warnings) {
                    if (callback) {
                        that._fireEvent("taskPostAdd", [ref]);
                        callback();
                    }
                }, null);
            });
        };


        this.copyPortfolioItem = function (ref, callback) {
            alert('hello');
            that._copyPortfolioItem(ref, undefined, that._copyAllFromBuffer);
            finishedCallback = callback;
        };      
    };
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
        /* Add app styles here */

  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    rally.addOnLoad(function() {
      var selectedValue = null;
      var tasksAdded = 0;
      var storiesAdded = 0;
      var portfolioitemAdded = 0;
      var searchPortfolioItem;
      var searchStories;
      var goButton, chooseButton;
      var chooser;
      var waiter;
      var dataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                                                          '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                          '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                                          '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

      function taskPostAdd(object, args) {
        tasksAdded = tasksAdded + 1;
        displayTasksAdded(tasksAdded);
      }

      function taskPreAdd(object, args) {
        dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding Task " + args.task.FormattedID + " - " + args.task.Name;
      }

      function storyPreAdd(object, args) {
        dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding User Story " + args.story.FormattedID + " - " + args.story.Name;
      }

      function storyPostAdd(object, args) {
        storiesAdded = storiesAdded + 1;
        displayStoriesAdded(storiesAdded);
      }

      function displayStoriesAdded(count) {
        dojo.byId("storyResult").innerHTML = "Stories added: " + count;
      }

      function portfolioitemPreAdd(object, args) {
        dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Adding PortfolioItem " + args.story.FormattedID + " - " ;
      }

      function portfolioitemPostAdd(object, args) {
        portfolioitemsAdded = portfolioitemsAdded + 1;
        displayPortfolioItemsAdded(portfolioitemsAdded);
      }

      function displayPortfolioItemsAdded(count) {
        dojo.byId("portfolioitemResult").innerHTML = "PortfolioItems added: " + count;
      }   

      function displayTasksAdded(count) {
        dojo.byId("taskResult").innerHTML = "Tasks added: " + tasksAdded;
      }


      function portfolioitemCopied(portfolioitem) {
        dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "Copy complete: ";
        var link = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Link({
          item: portfolioitem,
          text: portfolioitem._refObjectName
        });

        link.display('currentInfo');
        goButton.setEnabled(true);
        chooseButton.setEnabled(true);
        if(waiter) {
          waiter.hide();
          waiter = null;
        }
      }   

      function buttonPressed() {
        if (selectedValue) {
          var config = {
            eventListeners:{
              portfolioitemPreAdd:portfolioitemPreAdd,
              portfolioitemPostAdd:portfolioitemPostAdd,            
              storyPreAdd:storyPreAdd,
              storyPostAdd:storyPostAdd,
              taskPreAdd:taskPreAdd,
              taskPostAdd:taskPostAdd
            }
          };
          portfolioitemsAdded = 0;
          displayPortfolioItemsAdded(portfolioitemsAdded);
          tasksAdded = 0;
          displayTasksAdded(tasksAdded);
          storiesAdded = 0;
          displayStoriesAdded(storiesAdded);
          dojo.byId("currentInfo").innerHTML = "";
          var copy = new rally.PortfolioItemDeepCopy(dataSource, config);
          goButton.setEnabled(false);
          chooseButton.setEnabled(false);
          waiter = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait({});
          waiter.display('wait');
          copy.copyPortfolioItem(rally.sdk.util.Ref.getRelativeRef(selectedValue), portfolioitemCopied);
        }
      }

      function onChooserClose(chooser, args) {
        if (args.selectedItem) {
          selectedValue = args.selectedItem;
          goButton.setEnabled(true);
          dojo.byId('portfolioitemBox').innerHTML = args.selectedItem.FormattedID + ' - ' + args.selectedItem.Name;
        }
      }

      function showChooser() {
        var chooserConfig = {
          fetch:"FormattedID,Name,Description",
          type: "PortfolioItem",
          title: "Feature Chooser"
        };
        chooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, dataSource);
        chooser.addEventListener('onClose', onChooserClose);
        chooser.display();
      }

      rally.addOnLoad(function () {
        goButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
          text: "Copy",
          enabled: false
        });
        goButton.addEventListener('onClick', buttonPressed);
        goButton.display('goButton');

        chooseButton = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Button({
          text: "Choose"
        });
        chooseButton.addEventListener('onClick', showChooser);
        chooseButton.display('chooseButton');

        showChooser();

        rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.setHelpTopic("252");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div style="float:left">
      <span id="chooseButton"></span>
      <span id="portfolioitemBox" style="line-height:18px;vertical-align:middle">[No feature selected]</span>
      <span id="goButton"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="wait" style="float:left; height: 16px; width: 24px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px;padding-top:10px;clear:both">
      <div id="currentInfo" style="height:16px"></div>
      <div id="portfolioitemResult" style="margin-top:10px"></div>
      <div id="storyResult"></div>
      <div id="taskResult"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) there is no object "feature". Please try either portfolioitem/feature or portfolioitem and then filter out by _type, e.g.

`if(results.pi[i]._type == "PortfolioItem/Feature"){ //...`
as shown [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/pi-with-appsdk1/blob/master/pi-features-appsdk1.html).

Since you are using a legacy AppSDK1 I assume you are setting a version to 1.43 as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182698/feature-deep-copy-in-rally/24190836#24190836).

Comment: thnx @nickm ..I modified the code                                  key: "pi", type: "portfolioitem", still getting the error. Requested type name “feature” is unknown.

Comment: Check the instances where you use type variable that you set on line 51 of the code that you posted to var type = "feature"

Comment: I changed that in my code.I wrote this in function as u told dataSource.findAll(queryObject, copyPortfolioItem); and I am calling from other function as                                          chooser = new rally.sdk.ui.Chooser(chooserConfig, dataSource); but it is giving dataSource is not defined error

Comment: In the below code its returns feature but it should be portfolio/feature as feature is unknown type in WS API. <blink> function getTypeFromRef(ref) {
 if (rally.sdk.util.Ref.isRef(ref)) {
  var list = ref.split("/");
  alert(list);
  list.pop();
  return list.pop();
 }
 else {
  throw "Function getTypeFromRef expected a Rally Reference.";
 }
} </blink>